# Why can't EF assign my child collection when the constructor is private?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity that looks like this

```
public class SlideSet {
    public SlideSet(string name) : this() {
       Name = name
    }
    public SlideSet() {
        Params = new HashSet<SlideSetParameter>();
    }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SlideSetParameter> Params { get; set; } 
}
```

I just noticed that I'm not actually using the second constructor ever and that it actually makes no sense in my domain so I made it private. All of a sudden the Params array stopped loading and always gives me a length of 0. What's going on? In order for it to load I need my constructor to be at least protected. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the conditions for EF to be able to create proxies (necessary for lazy loading) is

> The class must have a public or protected parameter-less constructor.

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/12/22/poco-proxies-part-1.aspx) (an old link, but this part still applies)

The proxy is a derived type and it must be able to call the parameterless constructor of the base type.

Comment: So what is [this article](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters/) talking about?

Comment: Yes, EF will be able to materialize your types, but without lazy loading. So I can imagine that some test will succeed, as long as LL is not required. It may not be bad at all, by the way, to prevent lazy loading, but I think I would not exclude it on the model level. A protected constructor is OK for me.

Comment: To confirm this, someone commented "Doesnt work with lazy loading an navigational properties. Use protected!" Julie: "haha, I hate lazy loading so never tried it. I guess I better look."

Comment: Yeah, I hate lazy loading too, wonder if there's a way to get EF to always `.Include` everything automatically in my aggregate root. Another SO question coming up...

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing it but for the life of me I can't find an answer for whether its possible to just tell EF to always eager load an AR.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your default constructor set to public, as that is what Entity Framework is going to use to create your objects. Having it as private, it is unable to initialize the `Params` property, and therefor is trying to add any `SlideSetParameter`s to a null object.

Comment: I don't understand why the constructor on `SlideSet` would affect that property though. [This article from Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters/) says that private constructors and private setters are perfectly valid

Comment: Interesting. I'm using EF6 on my current project. I tried having private properties for DB Mapping, but they would never get set when loading the object, so I had to go with public gets, and protected internal sets. The easiest way for you to test would be to put a break point in both constructors to see if either is hit when you load objects. Otherwise, it's creating its own default constructor and skipping your initialization.